# CSS file don't not create with webpack

Tags: css, sass, webpack

I use webpack and i would like generate my CSS file with SASS.

So i've add css-loader and sass-loader. But, webpack don't create my CSS folder. My webpackconfig :

```
const webpack = require('webpack'),
      ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin'),
      BrowserSyncPlugin = require('browser-sync-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './js/app.js',
    output: {
        path: './public',
        filename: 'app.bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'stage-2']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loaders: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(["style", "css", "sass"])
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('app.bundle.css'),
        new BrowserSyncPlugin(
            {
                host: 'localhost',
                port: 3000,
                server: { baseDir: ['./'] }
            }
        )
    ]
}
```

Do you have any idea ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the style!css!sass loaders. Just install them using npm and set the config below in your webpack.config.

```
{
   test: /\.scss$/,
   loader: 'style!css!sass?sourceMap'
}
```

Your final webpack.config should look like this:

```
const webpack = require('webpack'),
      ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './js/app.js',
    output: {
        path: './js',
        filename: 'app.bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'stage-2']
                }
            },
            {
              test: /\.scss$/,
              loader: 'style!css!sass?sourceMap'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ]
}
```

Now your CSS should be bundled properly.

Comment: Replase first `loader` with `rules` and second `loader` with `use`. They are new version.

Answer (score -1):

`plugins` should be a root property, not a property of `module`.

```
const webpack = require('webpack'),
      ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './js/app.js',
    output: {
        path: './js',
        filename: 'app.bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'stage-2']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css!sass')
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('app.bundle.css')
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hi riscarrott, i've try but no result, CSS file is not generate with your config

Comment: @StéphaneR. I think you may need the style-loader too, and the extract text plugin takes a filename, not a path (it's path is determined by the output options above) https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin#usage-example-with-css

Comment: @StéphaneR. Also, you had `loaders` instead of `loader` when defining your scss loader

Comment: No result too, i've edit my first post with my actual config :(

Comment: This is pretty much a game of spot-the-difference but I think this is the last problem -- `ExtractTextPlugin.extract(["style", "css", "sass"])` should be `ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style", "css!sass")`.

Answer (score -2):

You have to import the scss file somewhere, like your index.js or App.js:

e.g. `import './sass/main.scss';`